# How does this shunt regulator work?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, design

I'm investigating battery monitors and I'm looking at TI's [BQ76930](http://www.ti.com/product/BQ76930/technicaldocuments) to take care of an 8 cell 24V LiIon. They provide the datasheet for their [evaluation module](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvu925a/slvu925a.pdf) (PDF warning) which includes the board schematic on Page 29. What I'm trying to figure out is the shunt regulators they've put in between the cells, which stack on top of each other. Here it is redrawn:

[image]

If the design works properly, the PFET should kick on and drain the overcharged cell into the 100ohm load. I don't see how their design can do that. Supposing that D1 can be reverse biased, there's nowhere for the current to go; the ADC pin is high impedance and the TVS diodes shouldn't kick in under normal operation. From what it looks like here, the PFET will always be firmly off.

Secondly, 5.6V is crazy high for a LiIon and the battery will have long since exploded.

So, what's up with TI's design here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detail you might be missing is that the ADCPIN is not always high impedance, because this device has internal cell balancing.  The external P-MOSFETs are for external balancing, which allows for faster balancing and better input filter for the ADC.

When the internal balancing is turned on, then adjacent ADC inputs are pulled together.  For illustrative purposes, imagine a low-value resistor suddenly connected across C1 in your circuit.  This basically pulls down Q1A's gate, turning it on.

Here's an example that although uses a different chip and N-MOSFETs instead of P-MOSFETs, might help explain how it works (in general terms):

[image]

I also found a related P-MOSFET example provided by TI in [this forum](http://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/battery_management/f/180/t/82920.aspx):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Balancing is not automatic- nor is it even done by the BQ monitor chip. The  BQ chip pulls adjacent Vc pins together on command- and those external MOSFETs draw current when that happens. See this document. http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluub41/sluub41.pdf

The Zener diodes are there to protect the MOSFET gates.